# Generate two negative binomial distributed random variables with predefined correlation

Tags: r, random, probability, correlation

Assume I have a negative binomial distributed variable X1 with NB(mu=MU1,size=s1) and a negative binomial distributed variable  X2 with NB(mu=MU2,size=s2).
I fitted a negative binomial regression to estimate Mu's and size's from my data

I can use the `rnbinom()` function in R to generate random draws from this distribution.

```
X1model<-rnbinom(n=1000,mu=MU1fitted,size=s1fitted)
X2model<-rnbinom(n=1000,mu=MU2fitted,size=s2fitted)
```

Those draws are now independent. However how can I draw from those distributions, so that they exhibit a predefined correlation r, which is the correlation I observe between my original data X1,X2.

so that:

```
cor(X1,X2,method="spearman") = r = cor(X1model,X2model,method="spearman")
```

-or even better draw from those with any arbitrary preset correlation r

Comment: This link may be helpful: Modelling Dependence with Copulas in R https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/10/modelling-dependence-with-copulas-in-r/

Comment: Copulas will give correlated values, but not typically values with  the marginal correlation equal to the pre-specified value. What you're asking for is moderately difficult in general.

Comment: This seems be more a question about statistical sampling methods and doesn't really seem specific to R. The "how" to this is more of a statistical challenge. Therefore the question seems like a better fit for [stats.se] instead.

Comment: When doing, X1/(X1+X2) I observe a bimodality in this distribution. But I also observe this for uncorrelated  n.binomial distributed variables dependent on the parameters MU1,MU2,size1,size2. I want to investigate if the bimodality is stronger than observed by independent random draws, so I wanted to check in which correlation range X1 and X2 have to be to exhibit the distinct (more distinct than by chance) bimodality This is why I thought of generating correlated random draws. But maybe this is not even neccesary here and there are other options to test that? so I don't need to open this box?